Unable to create partition on a new external SATA HDD
I have a brand new SATA HDD, since a couple of years, laying around and was trying to create a partition today, which didn't work.
It is currently in an external HDD case, connected via USB 3.0.
First I tried to create a partition, using gnome-disk-utility 42.0, but it didn't even give me the option to do so. It shows a completely wrong size as well, for the Device! The HDD is supposed to be 4TB big:

I seem to be allowed to format the partition - without having any created, which results in an error. I'm not really an IT guy, but does this even make sense, since there are no partitions yet?

I installed GParted but the device doesn't even show up there.
The "Security" section seems to be completely missing on sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb:
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0                    
Standards:
    Likely used: 5
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY(may be)(cannot be disabled)
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 0   Current = ?
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee2bbc55df0
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 0014ee
    Unique ID   : 2bbc55df0
Checksum: correct

lsblk -l lists the disk with a size of 128P, which differs from the information, given by gnome-disk-utility:
n@DTDEV00:~$ lsblk -l | grep sdb
sdb         8:16   0   128P  0 disk

I googled the error, displayed in gnome-disk-utility, while formatting the non-existent partition:
Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdb' (udisk-error-quark, 0)

and tried a few solutions, but none worked so far.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

I also tried running e2fsck, with the alternate superblocks, listed above, which produced the exact same error.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb 
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0,00106437 s, 0,0 kB/s

n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo hdparm --security-unlock "xxxx" /dev/sdb 
security_password: "xxxx"

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK command, password="xxxx", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 0b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo hdparm --security-disable "xxxx" /dev/sdb 
security_password: "xxxx"

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="xxxx", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 0b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 0b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I googled for "SG_IO: bad/missing sense data" and tried the following:
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo sg_decode_sense 70 00 0b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Fixed format, current; Sense key: Aborted Command
Additional sense: No additional sense information

EDIT1:
I connected the Disk internally now to see if I would have more luck.
It shows up in the UEFI, but with a Size of 0.0GB:
enter image description here
I put my hand on it during boot, but it doesn't vibrate or make any noises, unlike when I connect it, via external HDD case.
The disk is not listed in GParted, the gnome-disk-utility or even under /dev, while internally connected.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i ata
[sudo] password for helln: 
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db6c7000-0x00000000db743fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009e01fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000009e02000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20bfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000a20c000-0x00000000d73ef017] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d73ef018-0x00000000d7408457] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7408458-0x00000000d7448017] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7448018-0x00000000d7456057] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7456058-0x00000000db536fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db537000-0x00000000db6c6fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db6c7000-0x00000000db743fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db744000-0x00000000dbc69fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000dbc6a000-0x00000000dcba8fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000dcba9000-0x00000000deffffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000df000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000041f37ffff] usable
[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x41f355000-0x41f37ffff]
[    0.000000] Memory: 16120456K/16722572K available (20480K kernel code, 4268K rwdata, 13196K rodata, 4824K init, 17360K bss, 601856K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.276289] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    2.415704] acpi_cpufreq: overriding BIOS provided _PSD data
[    2.452015] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 34816k
[    2.452764] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1140K
[    3.609028] ahci 0000:06:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    3.609821] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc800000 port 0xfc800100 irq 42
[    3.610541] ahci 0000:07:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 2 ports 6 Gbps 0x11 impl SATA mode
[    3.613129] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc700000 port 0xfc700100 irq 94
[    3.613133] ata3: DUMMY
[    3.613135] ata4: DUMMY
[    3.613137] ata5: DUMMY
[    3.613140] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc700000 port 0xfc700300 irq 98
[    3.922292] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.088043] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    4.088092] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    4.088464] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[    9.149722] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    9.149729] ata2.00: ATA-9: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, EMT03B6Q, max UDMA/133
[    9.150387] ata2.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    9.152516] ata2.00: Features: Trust Dev-Sleep NCQ-sndrcv
[    9.152876] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    9.156354] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    9.166971] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 850  3B6Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    9.624046] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    9.624348] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[    9.624357] ata6: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[   15.256046] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   15.256347] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[   20.888045] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 320)
[   21.078558] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem 1d4c28aa-ccac-4e18-a482-46a9c51dcf29 ro with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[   21.357534] systemd[1]: Configuration file /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
[   21.906033] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database

An IT friend of mine thinks the SATA Controller might be busted, on the HDD. I hope one of you guys can prove him wrong!
EDIT2:
@oldfred pointed out that i should be using gdisk in one of his comments.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for helln: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sdb: 281474976710656 sectors, 128.0 PiB
Model: USB3.0 DISK00   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B853D82B-7FB1-4D76-AC6C-41E88AB1DF55
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 281474976710622
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 281474976710589 sectors (128.0 PiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name

"Linux's error #5 is an I/O error. This almost always signifies failing hardware." ~ @kyodake
I tried to create a new GPT partition table with a single partition, but there were no changes made after writing:
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): y

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-281474976710622, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Last sector (2048-281474976710622, default = 281474976710622) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdb.
Unable to save backup partition table! Perhaps the 'e' option on the experts'
menu will resolve this problem.
Warning! An error was reported when writing the partition table! This error
MIGHT be harmless, or the disk might be damaged! Checking it is advisable.

Command (? for help): q
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sdb: 281474976710656 sectors, 128.0 PiB
Model: USB3.0 DISK00   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 0063280F-A75D-4935-8DAA-FF214725D3E5
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 281474976710622
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 281474976710589 sectors (128.0 PiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name

EDIT3:
I tried using smartctl fom the smartmontools package, as @oldfred suggested:
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Tue Jul  2 09:51:47 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
SMART support is: Unknown - Try option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sdb 
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo smartctl -s on -T permissive -T permissive -T permissive /dev/sdb 
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
                  Checking to be sure by trying SMART RETURN STATUS command.
SMART support is: Unknown - Try option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enable failed: scsi error aborted command
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdb 
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
n@DTDEV00:~$ sudo smartctl -t long -T permissive -T permissive -T permissive /dev/sdb 
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
                  Checking to be sure by trying SMART RETURN STATUS command.
SMART support is: Unknown - Try option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.Read SMART Data failed: scsi error aborted command

I can't enable SMART cause of the Read SMART Data failed: scsi error aborted command error and that prevents me from running any tests on it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please be patient! I'm just a lowly web dev and not one of you awesome IT cracks. :P
Kindest Regards
Nik

Does your USB adapter have separate power? Most USB ports do not have enough power for HDD. My adapter worked great with an SSD, but would not even spin up an older HDD. Also some older adapters were not configured for larger drives. Check specs.

Thanks for your response @oldfred! Yes it has an external power source and it's specs say up to 16TB.

Since over 2TiB, you have to use gpt partitioning, not old MBR. And should always have partition(s). You cannot run fsck on drive as it is for formatted extX family of format, usually ext4, now. I have always used gparted, but you can use gdisk, and now parted & fdisk work with gpt drives. sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb Gdisk my not be installed by default. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html

Thanks for the hint! I tried to create a partion using gdisk, but there were no changes made after writing @oldfred. See EDIT 2! Do you know what "Read error 5" is by any chance?

Linux's error #5 is an I/O error. This almost always signifies failing hardware.

Do you have desktop that you can plug drive into? Best way to test if adapter or cable is the issue. You can check drive with Smart Status. It is in Disks and icon in upper right or as an application. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools Do not know if that works with drive as external drive. You may also check WD as it has tools in Windows for check & repair of its drives.

@kyodake Thanks for the information. I updated my question accordingly to reflect that.

@oldfred Yes I plugged it into my desktop internally. See EDIT 1 for that matter.
Thanks for the suggestion with Smartmontools! See EDIT 3 for that approach.
I tried to install WD Discovery, but couldn't get the installer to run, following the instructions on their homepage. - Installer just won't start with and without admin privileges.

If Smart Monitor & WD tools do not work, it seems drive is dead. I am out of ideas. Is it still within warranty period?

@oldfred It sure seems that way. No, I'm out of warranty. I guess that's my own fault for buying an HDD and not immediately checking if it actually works. Thanks for your help!
